# Using more than one group for single layer in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, layers, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I have a huge number of layers in my geoserver that I have painstakingly imported and they all work correctly when viewed with GeoExplorer etc.

I want to know if there is any way to create set maps which show groups of these layers. I know how to group the layers together but don't know if i can use the same layer in multiple groups.

If this is entirely impossible, what is the best way to create set maps- using a new workspace/store for the layers that require duplicating?

The maps will eventually be linked into a server that hopefully will have different interactive maps created from the above.

Comment: Are they rasters or vectors? If vectors do they share a common schema or could the schemas be modified to one uniform so that all layers could be created with filters?

Comment: The are all vectors, they are currently all in the same schema- 'public'.I've only done what is available via the tutorials online- I've imported them all into pgAdmin which hasn't been configured differently from that stage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same layer in different layer groups as long as (a) the layer group is global (ie not local to a workspace) or (b) the layer is in the same workspace as the layer groups.